# Nuxt rendering static assets in localhost but not in production

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I added a `static`folder which has a `demos`folder inside. According to [this guide](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/) Nuxt will automatically serve these files. It's working in localhost but not in production. Why?

This is my `nuxt.config.js``

```
module.exports = {
  head: {
    script: [
      { src: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.7.1/dist/Chart.min.js' },
      { src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.7.5/beautify.js' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' }
    ],
    meta: [ { charset: 'utf-8' } ]
  },
  plugins: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    '~/plugins/filters'
  ],
  build: {
    extend(config) {
        config.resolve.alias['vue'] = 'vue/dist/vue.common'
    }
  },
  router: {
    middleware: 'auth'
  },
  css: [
    '@/styles/style.sass'
  ]
}
```

Comment: please, can you share an example of your source code (html part) with assets loading?

Comment: @NicolasPennec thanks! We already solved the issue. My backend co-worker simply told me "there was a problem with the Cloudfront indexation".

Comment: Just keep your static folder into root directory for production , then it will work fine.